# Getting most active has many models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a scenario where a person could have done multiple activities on the site. So my person activity looks like following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :activities
```

and similarly activity model

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
```

Now i want to find the users and their activities in the order of their recent activity of the site..

For example if User A has done Activites A and B today and User B has done Activity C about a week ago, then user A should be listed above User B.

This can be done by writing SQL query but i am not sure if their is a good railish way to do this thing.

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: which is the prevailing order? number of activities or recent activity? And which is the granularity of recency: day, hour ...

Comment: Activity.all(:order => 'created_at DESC') should do the job for you.

Comment: @Sam, you should probably expand your comment into an answer we can vote on and the OP can accept.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a rails way. If you're using Rails 3 you could try this:

```
Activity.order('created_at DESC')
```

If you're using Rails 2 you could do it like Sam said in the comment above

```
Activity.all(:order => 'created_at DESC')
```

and for example if you want only the last 10 activities or only the activities since yesterday, you could do this

```
Activity.order('created_at DESC').limit(10)
Activity.where('created_at >= ?', Date.yesterday.midnight).order('created_at DESC')
```